# How can I update specific elements in an array in MongoDB using an array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an object

```
customer = {
  customerName:"Rajesh",
  customerNum:"899111111111",
  products:[
    { 
      productName:"ABC",
      productPrize:"100",
      deliveyDate:"20/2/2022"
    },{ 
      productName:"def",
      productPrize:"22",
      deliveyDate:"22/2/2022"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have an array where I changed the **product names only** :

`updatedProduct = [ { productName:"cdf"},{ productName:"qqq"} ]`

How can I update only product names of the **customer** object in MongoDB using this( **updatedProduct** ) array.

I tried the use $set but it didn't worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
updatedProduct = [{ productName: "cdf" }, { productName: "qqq" }]
db.customer.udpateOne(
   { customerName: "Rajesh" },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            products: {
               $map: {
                  input: { $range: [0, updatedProduct.length, 1] },
                  as: "i",
                  in: {
                     $mergeObjects: [
                        { $arrayElemAt: ["$products", "$$i"] },
                        { $arrayElemAt: [updatedProduct, "$$i"] },
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```